# NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.1.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed the latest version of Android Studio and it started to give me problems when adding new libraries telling me that the NDK version is unknown but I installed the latest version of NDK and the problem is not solved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see how to write effective questions in stackoverflow. (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)And Provide us Logcat or Image which shows error.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading your build from Gradle 5.1.1 to 5.4.1+ ,and I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

cd to the project , and look for local.properties file

add the path of ndk directory there

```
#Sat Sep 07 00:10:37 IST 2019
ndk.dir=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045
sdk.dir=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
```

Clean the project and build the project again.